# How do you install shapely for Python 2.7 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, shapely, python-wheel

The installation instructions from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely say to download an executable installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely but that gohlke web page only offers binaries for shapely for Python 3.5, none for 2.x.

Comment: Binaries for all Python versions are back at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely.

Comment: Thanks! Was their disappearance just a temporary thing? Should we expect shapely binaries for Python 2.7 moving forward, or are they going away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the binaries for all Python versions are back up at Gohlke's web site, so this is now a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the older versions of shapely on PyPI have windows installers listed for download. For example, version 1.4.0 has downloads for Python 2.7:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.4.0

Seems a shame that there isn't a windows download in any of the recent releases.